# Why are fluorine-19 NMR spectra less affected by paramagnetic centers than other common nuclei?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, magnetism

I know that <sup>19</sup>F NMR spectra are less sensitive to paramagnetic centers as an empirical fact: it’s my experience and that’s what people in my lab have always been saying.

For instance, some of my samples are NMR silent in <sup>1</sup>H, <sup>13</sup>C, and <sup>11</sup>B, but not <sup>19</sup>F NMR. Why does <sup>19</sup>F NMR appear to be an exception? Any helpful literature will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

$\ce{^{19}F}$ has similar NMR properties to $\ce{^1H}$ except in particular for the much larger chemical shift tensor terms and resulting larger chemical shift anisotropy (CSA). As a result CSA relaxation is a significant contributor to $T_2$ relaxation at all field strengths/tumbling rates. For instance, considering a [simple model](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10858-019-00268-y)
$$\frac{1}{T_{2,\text{CSA}}}=\frac{2}{15}(\sigma_| - \sigma_\perp)^2 \omega_F ^2 \tau_c \left( \frac23 + \frac{1}{2(1+\omega_F^2\tau_c^2)}\right),$$
the $2/3$ term in parentheses means that even under slow tumbling (large $\tau _c $) the contribution of CSA to $T_2$ relaxation can be significant in $\ce{^{19}F}$ , since the CSA term $(\sigma_| - \sigma_\perp)$ can be 50 times larger than for protons. CSA for protons is typically a minor source of relaxation at intermediate to low fields and in liquids (fast tumbling).

Since the CSA term already makes line broadening an issue for $\ce{^{19}F}$ at all fields/tumbling rates, it follows that adding another relaxation mechanism (due to paramagnetic interactions, for instance) results in a *relatively* small change in the total linewidth.

*References*

(1) Lu, M.; Ishima, R.; Polenova, T.; Gronenborn, A. M. $\ce{^{19}F}$ NMR Relaxation Studies of Fluorosubstituted Tryptophans. *J. Biomol. NMR* **2019,** *73* (8–9), 401–409. https://doi.org/10.1007/s10858-019-00268-y.

Comment: I should add: $\ce{^{19}F}$ also has much greater sensitivity (slightly lower than $\ce{^{1}H}$) and is present at 100% natural abundance, which would explain why it is detected while the lower gamma  nuclei are difficult to observe.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. Here's a ref for your comment regarding abundance from my original answer that I've since deleted after seeing your answer/comment http://chem.ch.huji.ac.il/nmr/techniques/1d/row2/f.html